# What mean two dots on same transformer winding

Tags: transformer

I know the dot mean the start of the winding, but on this schematic the same winding have two dots, i can't find info regard this on internet so i come ask what that means.
I meassure the 7 and 5 and give infinite resistance.
That's from a TV PSU, not outputing any DC safe voltage, secondary coils are all 0V.

[image]

[Schemantic PDF download](https://www.electronica-pt.com/esquema/func-download/23588/chk,405aa1417965e50c63bb11582bdcceef/no_html,1/)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Mighty strange indeed!

Comment: Hey, did you figured out what was wrong with the schematics/ or the transformer?

Comment: Just looking at the schematics I have no idea what that coil 5-7 is used for, and on my PSU (also vestel garbage 17IPS10-3) it also seems open. 

Also i get the connection between 1 and 4. For which im starting to think the transformer is bad since 1 goes dirrectly to RECT AC

Comment: No, i end to order another PSU, but the problem was not with transformer

Answer (score 3):

That means you're out of luck with that diagram, they really screwed up. The direction of the first coil will not be able to be determined from the schematic. You could pull it out and run a waveform from a signal generator to determine the directions.

If the coil from 7 to 5 really is open (and you believe the schematic) the transformer is probably bad (or the schematic is wrong).

Comment: looks like the diode/capacitor network is across pins 5 and 7 (DIODE_OUT) ..... maybe the transformer is available with the 5-7 winding in either direction, and the two dots mean that it does not matter which version is used .... only guessing at it though

Comment: I have added the schemantic link on post. All parts and labels are correct with the board and schmenatic, only this seen incorrect or maybe have a hidden meaning for the manufacture?
Well i can try probe C919 to PIN 7 and check if theres a connection, if so the schemantic is ok and the transformer can be damaged? All other pins are OK and have the correct voltage, like RECT_AC, 6,3 NC, so i belive schemantic is correct

Comment: Added board picture